# App config problems

Tags: c#, excel-dna

I am using a library called Excel DNA which allows you to create excel addins.
I have created a C# library and a .dll.config file is created as usual.
Unfortunately excel needs the config file to be called .xll.config.

How do I change the output name of the config file to .xll.config?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the config file with the required name to the project, and set it to copy to the output folder.